# IFrame not supported the session values

Tags: php, cakephp, iframe

I am created the iframe application using cakephp3.0, session values not supported in **safari and IE** web browser. any one please help

Comment: iframes create new instances of web pages, they dont follow along with cookie information which is what you need in order for sessions to work

Comment: @iam-decoder But how its work on chrome and fire-fox web browser ?

Comment: because web-kit browsers allow it, both safari and IE have stricter rules

Comment: @iam-decoder  If have any solution to start session in an iframe

Comment: possibly find some way to pass the php session cookie into the iframe and have php recreate it before starting the session. maybe through a `$_GET` variable?